# How to solve binding issues

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a control that requires use of a checkbox to enable disable sections but i need to bind this to a class So I have done the following. So My question is how do I set the binding to the say for example IncidentBuilderProperty.IsEnabled should I do it code behind using a parameter.

```
<DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
   <Label Content="Display" />
   <CheckBox Name="chkDisplayAdvanced" IsThreeState="False" VerticalAlignment="Center"
             IsChecked="{Binding isEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</DockPanel>
```

But In My Model I have the property isEnabled Declared in the following way.

So my question is how would i access the property IncidentBuilderProperty.isEnabled bare in mind their is a screen for each property with this checkbox on it but referencing one custom control.

```
public class AssignedToMeViewData : WizardData, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public ManagementPack ManagmentPack { get; set; }
    public List<BuilderProperties> BuilderProperty { get; set; }
    public BuilderProperties GeneralPage { get; set; }
    public Exception LastKnownException { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool IsNew { get; set; }

    public BuilderProperties IncidentBuilderProperty { get; set; }
    public BuilderProperties ProblemBuilderProperty { get; set; }
    public BuilderProperties ServiceRequestBuilderProperty { get; set; }
    public BuilderProperties ChangeRequestBuilderProperty { get; set; }
    public BuilderProperties RleaseRequestBuilderProperty { get; set; }
    public BuilderProperties ReviewActivityBuilderProperty { get; set; }
    public BuilderProperties ManualActivityBuilderProperty { get; set; }


    public class BuilderProperties
    {
        private bool isEnabled = true;
        public bool IsEnabled {
            get {
                return isEnabled;
            }
            set {
                if (isEnabled == value)
                    return;

                isEnabled = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of return why cant you write if (isEnabled != value)
      isEnabled = value;

Comment: @kishoreVM the question is not in how I have written the property but how to access it in binding please keep to the topic thanks.

Comment: try this: IsChecked="{Binding Path=IncidentBuilderProperty.IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}

Comment: @vidriduch is their anyway of doing that from the code behind of the control in that way as think would need to do it like that

Comment: in .xaml.cs try this.DataContext = IncidentBuilderProperty;, but this might mess the other IsEnabled ...

Comment: Please try this one and let me know if it works you.. FrameworkElement targetObject = chkDisplayAdvanced;
DependencyProperty targetProperty = CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty;
object sourceObject = IncidentBuilderProperty;//object of the actual Incidentbuilderclasss here
string sourceProperty = "IsEnabled";

var binding = new Binding(sourceProperty)
{
  Source = sourceObject,
  Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
};
targetObject.SetBinding(targetProperty, binding);

Comment: What's the control's `DataContext`? The `AssignedToMeViewData` object, or one of the `BuilderProperties`? Either way, you must bind the `IsEnabled` (capital 'I') *property*, not the `isEnabled` (lower-case 'i') *field*.

Comment: @Sphinxxx yes its the AssignedToMeView data that is that is the context but its the ISEnabled within each List I want to bind to how would I achieve that

Comment: @Sphinxxx If you could give a proper answer I will mark you up thanks budy

Comment: @kishoreVM you forgot to say what sourceProperty should be

Comment: I have mentioned sourceProperty as "IsEnabled"; in the var binding object creation i am using it as new Binding(sourceProperty)

Comment: @kishoreVM yes that worked i didnt see it inline the comment hide it friday momment

Comment: I will add my comment content in the solution.If it solved your problem please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Having an `AssignedToMeViewData` in the control's `DataContext`, you can set up binding to all your `BuilderProperties` like this in xaml:

```
<DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
    <Label Content="Display" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="chkIncident" IsChecked="{Binding IncidentBuilderProperty.IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="chkProblem" IsChecked="{Binding ProblemBuilderProperty.IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="chkService" IsChecked="{Binding ServiceRequestBuilderProperty.IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="chkChanges" IsChecked="{Binding ChangeRequestBuilderProperty.IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    ...
</DockPanel>
```

*But note that `Mode=TwoWay` is the default for `CheckBox.Checked`, so you don't need to specify that.*

If you have to do this from the code-behind instead, you can set up bindings like so:

```
chkIncident.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, 
                       new Binding("IncidentBuilderProperty.IsEnabled"));
chkProblem.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, 
                       new Binding("ProblemBuilderProperty.IsEnabled"));
chkService.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, 
                       new Binding("ServiceRequestBuilderProperty.IsEnabled"));
...
```

*See kishore's comment to your question for more advanced options when creating bindings from code-behind.*

Comment: I dont want to have four checkbox on screen anyway making them inviisble

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. What exactly is it that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

please try the following code snippet

```
FrameworkElement targetObject = chkDisplayAdvanced;
DependencyProperty targetProperty = CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty; 
object sourceObject = IncidentBuilderProperty;//object of the actual Incidentbuilderclasss here
string sourceProperty = "IsEnabled"; 
var binding = new Binding(sourceProperty) { 
    Source = sourceObject, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay 
    };
targetObject.SetBinding(targetProperty, binding);
```